# contour integrals parametrising and solving

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Use Cauchy's integral formula to compute the following:

$$\int \limits_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{-z}}{z-1}dz$$ where $\Gamma$ is the square with parallel sides to the axes, centre $i$ and side length $5$ traversed in the anticlockwise direction.

So do I split this integral into four parts? Would this parametrisation work:

Parametrise $\Gamma$: Define $\gamma (t)=p+t(q-p)$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{C}$ and $t \in [-1,0]$?

Comment: Did you try using Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, do not split up the integral. Since $f(z) = e^{-z}$ is analytic inside and on $\Gamma$, and since $z_0 = 1$ lies inside $\Gamma$, your integral, which is $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0}$, is equal to $2\pi i f(z_0) = \frac{2\pi i}{e}$ by Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: What did you define $\Gamma$ to be? And what point ($z_0$ or $w$) did you use for the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: @snowman $\Gamma$ is how you defined it.

Comment: how do you know what $z_0$ is?

Comment: @snowman I defined $z_0 = 1$ and $f(z) = e^{-z}$, so you could recognize that your integral is of the form $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0}$. Now you have a setup to apply the [Cauchy integral formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html).

Comment: I get how you find the answer now but what is the point of the question giving info on the length of each side, where the centre is, etc?

Comment: @snowman without that information, how would you know whether of not $\Gamma$ contains $1$ in its interior?

Comment: I see. One more thing, would point 2.5 be interior? If it touches the sides, is it still classed as interior?

Comment: @snowman $2.5$ is a boundary point, not an interior point, of $\Gamma$.